# LoginDate Different than LastLogin

Tags: reporting, login-history

I have a report which groups the **user logins per month**.
In this report, the **grouping** is done using the *Login Date* field (but the aggregation of it is set to Month, so we will have January 2020 and so on). In the columns I also have *Last Login* field.

I have two problems:

- I suppose the Login Date should be Equal to Last login which is not. I understood that maybe I should filter for *ClientType* to be equal to "browser" and in my case "OAuth". I did that, but the data is still not clean.
- for January 2020, I also get the login records which have *LastLogin* equal to December last year. Somehow, Salesforce does not group the records correctly.

Can you please help me? I do not find a logic explanation.

Comment: Isn't "Login Date" just a date/time of logins over the selected period of time in the report? And "Last Login" is the effective last login of the user

Comment: @Novarg you are right. I investigated better and realised that Login History actually stores also the failed attempts of logins but on the user, you have the last date of the successful login. Thanks!